# Getting value from followup fieldset when prior one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to dynamically create fieldsets on button click. Let say first time I click button it creates Definition 1 then Definition 2 then Definition 3 etc.
Each fieldset has X mark to remove the dynamically created fieldset if one was created by accident.
What I am trying to do is for example Definition 2 fieldset was deleted then Definition 3 one should say Definition 2. 
What I need to know is when I click X mark in one fieldset, grab the value of the legend from the next fieldset and change it to the value of the one deleted.

Here is what my dynamic call looks like:

```
    if($(".addDef").length > 0){
                    i++;
                }else{
                    i = 2;
                }
    $(".definitionBlock").append("<fieldset><legend class='addDef'>Definition #"+ i +"</legend><div class='removeDef'><span>&#10006;</span></div>
    </fieldset>");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.text(function(index, text){})` to replace digit portion of `.textContent` with index of element within collection

```js
var n = 2;

$(".addDefBtn").on("click", function() {
  if (!$(".addDef").length) {
    n = 2;
  }
  $(".mvnDefinitionBlock").append("<fieldset class='addDef'><legend class='addDefTitle'>Definition #" + n++ + "</legend><div class='removeDef'><span>&#10006;click</span></div></fieldset>");
});

$('body').on('click', '.removeDef', function() {

  $(this).closest('fieldset').remove();
  n = 2;
  $(".addDef legend").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/\d+/, n++);
  });
});
```

```css
.removeDef {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a href="#" class="addDefBtn">Add New Definition</a>
<div class="mvnDefinitionBlock"></div>
```

Comment: interesting you have span within the legend.. i tried to put this fiddle together .. what am i doing wrong here? I have span outside of legend
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzxW4/185/)

Comment: @coder Updated jQuery version to 3.2.1 `$('body').on('click', '.removeDef', function() {
   $(this).closest('fieldset').remove();
   $(".addDef legend").text(function(index, text) {
     return text.replace(/\d+/, index + 1);
   });
 });` http://jsfiddle.net/vzxW4/186/

Comment: very close thank you. It's just definition #2 (first one) should stay as 2 and not turn to 1 if I delete definition #3

Comment: really only fieldsets that follow the one deleted should change